# Play a sound from library with the space bar in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been trying to come up with a simple code that plays a sound "jump" from the library each time the spacebar is pressed, but no luck. Everything I try turns my fla/swf into a strobe light.

Answer (score 1):

```
var spacebarDown:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, _keyHandler);

function _keyHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        switch(e.type)
        {
            case KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN:

                if(!spacebarDown)
                {
                    spacebarDown = true;

                    // Play Sound.
                    var sfx:YourSound = new YourSound();
                    sfx.play();
                }

                break;


            case KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP: spacebarDown = false; break;
        }
    }
}
```